# Turn a git sub-directory into a git repository?

Tags: git, heroku

I have a repository that has a directory for each component, such as Android vs. iPhone vs. webapp, etc. I want to push the webapp up to Heroku, but I don't want to rework my directory structure.

In essence, what I want to do is push only a portion of my tree up to Heroku. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the ideal way to organize your application would be via git submodules (see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git). This way, you could have your main application structured like:

```
proj
├── android
└── iphone
```

Where `android` and `iphone` each have their own Git repository, and are simply git submodules.

If you'd like a good introduction to Git submodules, you should check this out: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules